# Get Xml from Class library project

Tags: c#, class-library

I have one class library project in c# which contains some XML files in one folder. 
I want to use these XML files in the project but I'm not able to get Xml file path from code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embed the xml files in the library.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "com.example.resource.xml";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```